# Auto update tomcat application

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I'm looking for a solution to auto update an application installed on a tomcat server.

The application I am coding should update itself when a newer version is available on a public server. 
It is important to say that the client install himself the war file on its own server.

How can I do that without asking the client to create a program called by a cron task to update the war file if needed ?

The goal is that all the client use the same version of the application.

Comment: Do you have access to client's tomcat? You can deploy the new war using tomcat admin tools from the central server. For example with an ant task. If not, create a second application to check and deploy

Comment: In a secure Tomcat environment, an application can't write just anywhere to the local disk. To allow an application to create or update files in Tomcat's deployment directory would be a pretty big security hole.

Comment: Was looking for same information, updating from app itself, but the crontab as you propose is fine for me. Anyway at 3am tomcat service is restarted, so I'll add a download and some script to test the version. once ready and tested I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this from within your application if the `manager` application is already installed. Simply write a periodic process (e.g. Quartz, or write your own poor-man's cron in Java) that pings the central server for updates.

If your update server is smart enough to do this, you should be able to simply make an `HTTP GET` request with an `If-Modified-Since` header so you'll either get a `304 Not Modified` response or you'll get a `200 OK` with the updated WAR file. If you get a 304, do nothing.

If an update is found, download the updated WAR file (into memory, or stream it) while simultaneously making a connection to the `manager` application to [deploy the new version](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Archive_(WAR)_Remotely).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can have a daemon thread [the java program will be part of the app] running to check for an update version from a repo. Once available, the threading program can  fetch the latest version. And then install the latest app by overwriting the existing one. Reload the app context.